# Approximate non-periodic function with Fourier series

Tags: fourier-transform

Given the  Fourier series
\begin{align}
f_0(x)=1 \\
f_1(x)=\cos(x)\\
f_2(x)=\sin(x) \\
f_3(x)=\cos(2x)\\
f_4(x)=\sin(2x) \\
f_5(x)=\cos(3x)\\
f_6(x)=\sin(3x) \\
\cdots
\end{align}
where $x\in [-\pi, \pi]$, can one approximate a non-periodic function (e.g. $y=x/10, x\in [-\pi, \pi]$) with a linear combination 
$$
y(x) =\sum_i a_i f_i(x)
$$ ?

As I understand, all Fourier series here satisfy
$$
f_i(-\pi)= f_i(\pi)
$$
then $y(-\pi)=   y(\pi)$ holds, which means that $y(x)$ is periodic.

Comment: It makes no sense to say that the function defined on an interval is periodic or not. The Fourier series approximates a function on $x\in [-\pi, \pi]$, and as a side effect "extends" it periodically over $\mathbb R$

Comment: @user58697, you are right. Actually I am asking a more basic question: why a series of functions $f_i$,  $f_i(-\pi)= f_i(\pi)$, adding them together can approximate another function y(x) which $y(-\pi) \neq y(\pi)$

Answer (score 1):

The question is : approximate in what sense? If you want to approximate in the pointwise sense then you have to assume that $f$ is periodic. But there are other types of approximations. Any square integrable function can be approximated by the partial sums $s_n$ of a series of above type in the sense $\int |f-s_n|^{2} \to 0$. No periodicity is required for this.

Comment: I am only focusing on two end points: $y(-\pi)$ and $y(\pi)$.  If the Fourier series  satisfy $f_i(-\pi)= f_i(\pi)$, why adding them together can approximate a function y(x) which $y(-\pi) \neq y(\pi)$?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer you cannot write a non-periodic function $y$ as $\sum a_n f_n(x)$ if this equation is suppose to hold in the sense that that partial sums of the series converge at every point to $f(x)$. Even if you want convergence at just the points $\pm \pi$ you cannot do this. Up to this point you are right. But there are other types of convergence of a series of functions where the partials sums need not converge at any point.

Comment: Have you come across $L^{2}$ theory of Fourier series? If so then you would understand what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier series $f(x)$ of $y(x)~($periodic with $2\pi)$ is not identical to $y(x)$ even in the specified interval. The [Dirichlet conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions) give that the series converges to the average of the left and right-hand limits of $y$ at each $x$. This means it converges to $y(x)$ at points of continuity. At points of discontinuity, its values does not match with the functional value.

This means $f(\pi)=f(-\pi)=\dfrac{y(\pi^-)+y(-\pi^+)}2$. In case $y(x)$ is continuous at $\pm\pi$ but $y(\pi)\ne y(-\pi)$, the value of the Fourier series does not agree with $y$. This is a consequence of $y$ not being periodic.